# Python csv.writer trouble

Tags: python-3.x, csv, writer

To track a password update script, I want to write a log of connections, so I wrote my code as follows, I put you only one part, there is also the return for a socket problem and for a successful connection.

The problem arises at the level of the return in the file csv, I have commas everywhere!

[Here](https://github.com/xdouillard/NetworkPass) the GitHub link, I can't embed image

`pass_cisco_change.py`

`journal.csv`

How can I remove all these commas?

Comment: Please post your code and actions explicitly not via a link.

Comment: improving formatting and grammar

Answer (score 0):

Code

```
ip_address = sys.argv[1] 
username = sys.argv[2]
password = sys.argv[3]
new_pw = sys.argv[4]

ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy() )
try:
    ssh_client.connect(ip_address, 22, username, password, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
    result = "Authentication failed"
    with open("journal.csv", "a") as suivi:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(suivi)
        csv_writer.writerows([ip_address,result])`
```

Result :

```
1,9,2,.,1,6,8,.,0,.,1
A,u,t,h,e,n,t,i,c,a,t,i,o,n, ,f,a,i,l,e,d
```